# How to access a device within a WiFi AP from outside?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

I have three devices: A desktop, a server (local), and a laptop. My server and laptop are connected through a WiFi device (My server should be on LAN, but some other issues prevent me from doing that right now), while the desktop is hooked up to LAN (which the WiFi AP is also connected to). I can SSH into the server from my laptop easily, but I cannot access the server from my desktop. This is what my setup looks like (example IPs):

```
                      LAN (internet, DHCP)
                    /     \
Desktop (192.60.12.4)     WiFi AP (192.60.12.2, DHCP)
                        /         \
                   Laptop      Server (192.168.1.64, static)
```

What I need to do is setup the WiFi AP to provide access to the server from the outside. Unfortunately, port forwarding settings on the WiFi AP seem to only work in the opposite direction (e.g allows accessing desktop from within WiFi). [Here's a screenshot of my router port forwarding page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iZp5.png) It's a NanoStation M2 (running airOS). How do I get the server to be accessible to the desktop?

EDIT: I have no clue how the internet setup works - this was handed to me (I moved in). I'd be happy to share more information, but I don't know enough to provide the info without some directions.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the image, you have configured the WiFi device not as an AP, but as a `SOHO Router`. Since you don't want the NAT functionality, I recommend you reconfigure to `Access Point`

Comment: Switching from "SOHO Router" to "Router", or even just disabling NAT, prevents Internet access through WiFi.

Comment: The OQ says nothing about Internet access - how is it provided? And of course you have to harmonize the IP ranges on wired and wireless LANs.